# multiple select option not getting displayed properly

Tags: html, css

Following is my code

```html
<select id="accessList" name="accessList" multiple="multiple" style="position:relative;left:5px;overflow-x:auto;width:200px">
     <option value="36453" style="text-align:left;width:auto">TestGroupterminal121251221231321321321231321321231111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
</select>
```

Option value not displayed completly when option is **selected**.

Image below show non-selected vs selected :

[image]

Comment: here is the fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/5hmqdq1v/

Comment: how do you want it to be displayed? You put a `width: 200px` in style, so it's normal that it won't be visible.

Comment: but its showing when  it's not selected and width is given so it shows scroll bar after certain length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the `display:inline-block` on **option**, it makes **option** full `width` at selected.
Hope it helps.

```html
<select id="accessList" name="accessList" multiple="multiple" style="position:relative;left:5px;overflow-x:auto;width:300px">
     <option value="36453" style="text-align:left;display:inline-block">TestGroupterminal121251221231321321321231321321231111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It doesn't when I test your live example

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you can't do that (*despite Roy's answer seems to work in Chrome and Edge*).

**Why?**

When it's about styling `<select>`s, browsers have always been quirky. This is just another case. To be sure, I have loaded your fiddle in multiple browsers (all latest).

These are the results:

- Edge and Chrome exhibit the behavior you presented.
- Your code in Internet Explorer 11 and Firefox Developer edition (latest) simply doesn't work.
- Roy's code works in Edge and Chrome, but doesn't in IE 11 and Firefox.

This is the very reason why are so many select styling Javascript plugins out there.